# How to obtain the RepositoryService in JCR (Jackrrabit)?

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit

I want to perform some batch operations in JCR (Jackrabit), I need to use `org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.Batch` ([docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/jackrabbit/spi/Batch.html)), for this I need `RepositoryService` but I do not know how to obtain the `RepositoryService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RepositoryService is a low-level interface, used by the Jackrabbit SPI interfaces.

In general, you do batch operations in JCR by do several operations and then calling Session.save().

Comment: so I do not get faster node creation (for millions of nodes) by using `RepositoryService`?

Comment: I managed to obtain the a `RepositoryService`, but How can I obtain a `org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.ItemId` for a Node?

Comment: You really need to provide more details. AFAIU, you are using Jackrabbit Oak (as you are using MongoDB). Oak doesn't even *have* a RepositoryService API.

Comment: actually we want to migrate some very old `JCR` repository data to the new version oak (not just nodes, because the data model is different and we need to perform some processing before creating new nodes, that is NOT expensive at all, some thing like changing node's property name .etc) the process of creating new nodes in the destination `JCR` is very very slow.